# How to connect existing telephony system with Zendesk?

Tags: zendesk, zendesk-api

I have existing telephony system and now I want to integrate into zendesk, I have gone through Talk Partner Edition API but I am not getting exact idea. I am ready with softphone and all calling feature at my own now how should I connect this existing app with zendesk and how should I embed this softphone into Zendesk?
Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you looked at this Zendesk Help Center article?  It provides more details about a sample workflow and development suggestions for how to accomplish.  https://develop.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/360001804788--Embedding-a-softphone-in-Support

Comment: Yes. I have gone through it. But I didn't get the exact idea to integrate existing system with Zendesk support, there they have concentrated on developer guide in the apps framework documentation.

Comment: which parts do you understand and which parts do you get stuck on?  the basic idea is to build a soft phone with zendesk apps framework, send an api request to zendesk rest talk api endpoint from your server when a call comes in, and then this can trigger the creation of a ticket, user profile, and the soft phone to open to the agent.